# Raspberry Camera compile error: undefined reference to symbol

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I am trying to compile a program for the raspberry pi.
But when I run the build in Geany I got this error:

```
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs) -o g++ $(pkg-config raspicam --cflags --libs) -o camera_2 camera_2.cpp (in directory: /home/pi/Desktop)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTDUfOT.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE'
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.405: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

The camera.cpp file looks like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <raspicam_cv.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace raspicam;

Mat frame;

void Setup ( int argc,char **argv, RaspiCam_Cv &Camera )
  {
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  ( "-w",argc,argv,400 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,  ( "-h",argc,argv,240 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, ( "-br",argc,argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_CONTRAST ,( "-co",argc,argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_SATURATION,  ( "-sa",argc,argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_GAIN,  ( "-g",argc,argv ,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FPS,  ( "-fps",argc,argv,100));

  }


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    Setup(argc, argv, Camera);
    cout<<"Connecting to camera"<<endl;
    if (!Camera.open())
    {       
        cout<<"Failed to Connect"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"Camera Id = "<<Camera.getId()<<endl;
     
    Camera.grab();
    Camera.retrieve(frame);

    imshow("frame", frame);
    waitKey();
    return 0;  
}
```

So far I have figured that when I remove
`Mat frame;`
the error does not appear.

The pkg-config file looks like this:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv4/opencv2
includedir_new=${prefix}/include/opencv4


Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 4.5.5
L: -Libs${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio
Libs.private: -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

The command in Geany looks like this:

```
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs) -o g++ $(pkg-config raspicam --cflags --libs) -o %e %f
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong and what I do have to change?
Thank you

Comment: Huh? You can't run `g++ ... -o g++ ...` because you will overwrite your compiler, or make something in your current directory that looks like a compiler. Just have one `-o XXXX` where `XXX` is the name of your compiled program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Altogether I have two build commands:
```
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs) -o %e %f
g++ $(pkg-config raspicam --cflags --libs) -o %e %f
```
Should I run them separetly or can I combine them?
I am running them in rasbian Geany IDE in 'Set Build commands'

Comment: I don't actually know what you have or what you are trying to do, but you can probably do `g++ $(pkg-config ...) $(pkg-config ...) -o %e %f`

Comment: Thank you I have tried it:
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs) $(pkg-config raspicam --cflags --libs) -o %e %f

But I still get the error. I want to compile opencv and raspicam for a project.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `-o g++` is very weird because it will make an output file named `g++`, which is confusing because that's also the name of your compiler.  You probably want to remove that since you already have a `-o` argument.

Secondly, the order of the different objects/libraries that are getting linked together often matters when you are linking a program.  Try putting the calls to `pkg-config` at the end of the command.

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted the command as above. How should it look when putting 'pkg-config' to the end?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error.
I have added two libraries to the command:

```
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs) $(pkg-config raspicam --cflags --libs) -o %e %f -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

I wonder why the libraries do not work in the config file.

Comment: Finally I have find out how to have all libraries in the pkg-config file.
This line was wrong:
```L: -Libs${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio```
It should be:
```Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core ...
```